# How to turn string into objects with properties

Tags: javascript, split

I'm fetching a string that looks like this

```
Ebonie Rangel
7175 Yukon Street
(507) 833-3567
Geography
Keenan Ellwood
2 Elm Lane
(894) 831-6482
History
Kailan Smart
795 Harvard Street
(925) 856-5167
Biology
Kaydan Hirst
9 East Lakeview Ave.
(939) 812-6141
Programming
Isabelle Prentice
700 Rock Maple St.
(899) 875-8627
Math
```

and I'm trying to create an array of objects for each person from the string to have something like this

```
[
 {
  name: 'Ebonie Rangel',
  address: '7175 Yukon Street',
  phone: '(507) 833-3567',
  course: 'Geography'
 },
 {
  name: 'Keenan Ellwood,
  address: '2 Elm Lane',
  phone: '(894) 831-6482,
  course: 'History'
 },
 ...etc
];
```

What I've tried is to split the string and create an array, and then to map through it and create properties there with values, but the problem is the string I fetched is already broken down by something and I cannot figure it out by what I should split it.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('get-text-btn');
      let textArea = document.getElementById('my-text-area');
      
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        loader.style.display = 'inline-block';
        fetch('https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt')
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              throw Error('Error while reading file.');
            }
            return response.text();
          })
          .then(function (text) {
            // textArea.innerHTML = text;
            const redovi = text.split('\n'); 

            const objekti = redovi.map((red) => {
              const [name, address, phone, course] = red.split('\n');

              return {
                name: name.trim(),
                address: address,
                phone: phone,
                course: course,
              };
            });
console.log(objekti)
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            textArea.innerHTML = 'Fetch problem: ' + err.message;
          })
          .finally(function () {
            loader.style.display = 'none';
          });
      });
```

```html
<button id="get-text-btn">Get Data</button>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <textarea id="my-text-area" rows="30"></textarea>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If each "record" is **always** four lines (name, addr, phone, subject) it seems reasonably straight-forward, but it's not clear what specific issue you're having.

Comment: The string is not properly split into objects and I cannot figure out why

Comment: You split the entire string on `\n` with `redovi = text.split('\n')` then map `redovi`. Each element of `redovi` will be a single line from the file, but you try to split it on `\n` again, AFAICT. That won't work; it's already been split. You likely mean to chunk it up four lines at a time and put each line into its respective object property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `split ('\n')` two times which does not make sense. After splitting the file into lines you have to count to know when the record is finished.

```js
let button = document.getElementById('get-text-btn');
      let textArea = document.getElementById('my-text-area');
      
      button.addEventListener('click', function () {
        loader.style.display = 'inline-block';
        fetch('https://v-dresevic.github.io/Advanced-JavaScript-Programming/data/students.txt')
          .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
              throw Error('Error while reading file.');
            }
            return response.text();
          })
          .then(function (text) {
            // textArea.innerHTML = text;
            const redovi = text.split('\n'); 
            
            let records = [];
            for (let i=0; i<redovi.length; i+=4)
            {
              records.push ({
                name: redovi[i].trim(),
                address: redovi[i+1].trim(),
                phone: redovi[i+2].trim(),
                course: redovi[i+3].trim(),
              });
            }
console.log(records)
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            textArea.innerHTML = 'Fetch problem: ' + err.message;
          })
          .finally(function () {
            loader.style.display = 'none';
          });
      });
```

```html
<button id="get-text-btn">Get Data</button>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <textarea id="my-text-area" rows="30"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const data = `Ebonie Rangel
7175 Yukon Street
(507) 833-3567
Geography
Keenan Ellwood
2 Elm Lane
(894) 831-6482
History
Kailan Smart
795 Harvard Street
(925) 856-5167
Biology
Kaydan Hirst
9 East Lakeview Ave.
(939) 812-6141
Programming
Isabelle Prentice
700 Rock Maple St.
(899) 875-8627
Math`.split('\n')

const result = []

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
  result.push({
    name: data[i],
    address: data[i + 1],
    phone: data[i + 2],
    course: data[i + 3]
  })
}

console.log(result)
```